# In how many ways 100 chocolates can be distributed to 3 children?

Tags: combinatorics

Tuktuki, Ikri and Halum are given 100 chocolates by their Uncle. If each of them receive at least one chocolate, then in how many ways can they distribute the chocolates among themselves?

---

@JMoravitz......you  gave an amazing and logical explanation. But, I was wondering why the technique that I used to solve gave a different result, and still I find my technique to be logical. My step by step approach is presented below :

let the first children be given n chocolates. Here,   1 <= n <= 98.

accordingly, in total, the second and third children, will get (100-n) chocolates.

Here, 2 <= (100-n) <= 99

Now, for every value (100-n) as expressed in the above inequality,

the number of possible ways of distribution between 2nd and 3rd children

=  `(n-1)/2    +     1/2`  ; if (100-n) is even  .................(i)

or, =  (n-1)/2  ;  if (100-n) is odd.....................(ii)

Summing up all the values obtained from equation (i) and (ii), by using all the values of (100-n) as per its mentioned range of values, we get 2450

I get that, the obtained sum is the number of ways of distribution among 3 children.

Now, I need all your help to verify this approach of mine. PLEASE HELP!!

Comment: It is helpful to state what you have already attempted in trying to solve the problem.

Comment: @RanganAryan if you want me to notice an important edit like the one you made, ping me in the comments section by writing `@JMoravitz` followed by a message that you want me to see.  As for your approach, no it is incorrect.  How many ways can you distribute $k$ chocolates between two people where each person gets at least one chocolate will be $k-1$.  There should be no division by two going on.  It is fine to approach in a more brute-force fashion like this with nested summations, but you need to make sure that what you are adding is correct at each step.

Comment: As for why the number of ways to distribute $k$ chocolates to two people where each person gets at least one is $k-1$, use the same argument as what I describe below, or more directly recognize that the second person could get any number of chocolates $1,2,3,\dots,k-1$ and depending on that choice the final person's number of chocolates will be forced.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The phrasing of the question is technically ambiguous whether or not the 100 chocolates are considered identical or not.  In almost every occurrence of a problem phrased in the way you present it, it is intended to be assumed that the chocolates are identical for all intents and purposes and the only thing we care about it the number of chocolates that each person receives.

This is a classic example of a problem solved by [Stars and Bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)).

The short explanation is that we can represent any manner of distributing the chocolates as a sequence of $\star$'s and $\mid$'s.

For a smaller example of only eight chocolates and three people the sequences

$$\star\mid\star\star\star\mid\star\star\star\star$$

corresponds to the first person getting one, the second person getting three, and the third person getting four

and

$$\star\star\star\star\star\star\mid\star\mid\star$$

corresponds to the first person getting six and the second and third persons each getting one.

Since each person gets at least one chocolate, we try to pick how many ways in which we can pick the locations of the bars in our stars-and-bars argument.  Convince yourself that in any valid arrangement of stars and bars where it corresponds to everyone getting at least one star that no two bars can be touching and no bar can be on the very edge.

Convince yourself also that any way of distributing chocolates can be uniquely described by such a stars and bars configuration and that any such stars and bars configuration corresponds uniquely to a way of distributing the chocolates.  (*I.e. there is a bijection between the two problems, implying the count must be the same for both*)

If there are $100$ stars, how many valid locations are there for bars to go?

> $99$ available locations

How many of these locations must we choose (*simultaneously*)?

> $2$

How many ways are there then to distribute?

> $\binom{99}{2}$

---

In the related but technically different question of when the chocolates are all distinct, you should approach via inclusion exclusion.

Letting $A_1,A_2,A_3$ be the sets of arrangements where the first person, the second person, and the third person don't receive any chocolates respectively, and $X$ is the set of arrangements of chocolates regardless, we are tasked with finding $|X\setminus (A_1\cup A_2\cup A_3)|$

By inclusion-exclusion principle, this becomes $|X|-|A_1\cup A_2\cup A_3|=|X|-|A_1|-|A_2|-|A_3|+|A_1\cap A_2|+|A_1\cap A_3|+|A_2\cap A_3|-|A_1\cap A_2\cap A_3|$

$|X|=3^{100}$ can be seen from a straightforward multiplication principle argument as each of the 100 distinct chocolates have three options for who will receive it.

$|A_i|=2^{100}$ again can be seen as if person $i$ doesn't receive any each chocolate has two choices on where to go.

$|A_i\cap A_j|=1^{100}=1$ as if person $i$ and person $j$ (*with $i\neq j$*) both receive no chocolates, all remaining chocolates must go to the remaining person.

$|A_1\cap A_2\cap A_3|=0$ trivially since it is impossible to distribute the chocolates to the three people and simultaneously none of the three get any chocolates.

This yields a final count of $3^{100}-3\cdot 2^{100}+3$ ways to distribute 100 distinct chocolates among three distinct people.

Comment: I would only add that if there are $n$ items to be distributed amongst $k$ labeled buckets where each bucket gets at least one; then that is the same problem as distributing $n-k$ items to $k$ buckets, where any bucket can be empty.

Comment: Indeed.  I personally learned how to derive the formula for empty buckets first, however many others had learned how to derive the formula for buckets which need at least one in each first.  Both are common enough that I opted to just give the gist of the derivation for the formula in this direct case.

Comment: Your post is well-tuned as is :).

Comment: @JMoravitz....this answer is correct only if the chocolates are identical.

Comment: @mathlover and your answer is incorrect regardless of assumptions made.  In *almost every* instance of a problem phrased in this manner, the items are intended to be assumed identical.  Still, you make a fair point and I will make it clear in my post that this was technically still an assumption I made.

Answer (score 0):

First each of them has to get at least one. So the n-Vektor (1|1|1) shows that each has already one! 
Second we have to distribute 97 Chocolates, if the author did not say if they=chocolates are distinct then the question is formulated open and you have to give two answer(thats my interpretation at least) so we have:

case a) they are distinct( have numbers from 1 to 97)
case b) they are all the same.

Lets have a look at case b) 
This is counted by $\binom{97+3-1}{97}=161700$

Now case a) we can choose for each of the 97 chocolates a number from 1 to 3 this can be done in $3^{97}$ ways.

I am not quite sure about the 3-chocolates. How does this looks like? 
p.s. why is the post voted down?